# Loop over files with specific name in specific folder

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to write a script but cannon think about anything fancy-looking (I'm kinda new to Python). Here is what I need. There is a root folder, I need to find all folders with a specific name in it, in those folders find a file with a certain name, in that file find a specific string and take a number from that string.

I tried doing os.walk etc. but don't know how to specify all conditions correctly. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! It just so happens that this information can be found in the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk).

Comment: You'll get better answers on this site if you post the code you've got so far and ask specific questions about the problems you have with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

def find(file):
    #your code to retrieve number from some file

def search(loc='.'):
    for content in os.listdir(loc):
        pth = os.path.join(loc, content)
        if os.path.isdir(pth): #is it a folder?
            if #specific-name-in-folder:
                search(pth)
        elif #it is a file, but if there is specific-name-in-file:
            find(pth)
```

use `os` and `os.path` to deal with file-system.